# How can I know in which websites I have created accounts using my Gmail ID?

Tags: account-management, google-account

For sign up in any website like Facebook, Pinterest we need to give our email ID. I have been using my Gmail ID almost in every case but after three, four years I have forgotten some sites in which I had created accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your account, click on [Dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard) under [Account](https://www.google.com/settings) in the left pane.

Find [Authorize Account Access](https://www.google.com/accounts/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en) and click on the link. Sign in again and you should get a list of all sites accessing your information through your google account.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different paths you can take to get to the list of authorized sites. Here's one:

1. Go to your [Google Account Settings](https://www.google.com/settings/account)
2. Click on [Security](https://www.google.com/settings/security) (in the left menu)
3. Scroll to the bottom under "Connected applications and sites" click the <kbd>Manage access</kbd> button

   - You will probably need to re-enter your password as a security measure
4. You are presented with a list of all the sites where you've used your Google Account (a.k.a. Gmail address). (You can revoke access for any of these by clicking the button next to it)